# Spring Mvc ModelAttribute with referencing name is not working?

Tags: spring, model, controller

I want to to create different `@Entity` entities within the same Controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="create", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String  GET(Model model) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
{
    Class<?> clazz = ????; // a Random POJO is chosen, i want to use POJOs!!

    Object object = clazz.newInstance();
    model.addAttribute("object", object);
    return "create";        
}

@RequestMapping(value="create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Object POST(@ModelAttribute(value="object") Object object)
{
    System.out.println("POST! got type: " + object.getClass().getName());
    return object;
}
```

In the Post Method I get NULL for `@ModelAttribute(value="object") Object object`

If I change it to `@ModelAttribute(value="object") realType object` it is working perfectly fine. But I don't know the type yet.

I thought the `@ModelAttribute` can achieve this anyway with the name "object" but apparently not. What am I missing?

Comment: Instead of dynamically binding the attribute object, why not just pass in a `Model`, and read out your `object` from there inside your controller. That should get around the setting null. You could also consider passing an attribute of type `Class<T>` for a typesafe conversion.

Comment: Do you mean something like:  
 public class ContentContainer {

 public Object content;
 
 public ContentContainer(){}
 
 public ContentContainer(Object object){
  setContent(object);
 }

 public Object getContent() {
  return content;
 }

 public void setContent(Object content) {
  this.content = content;
 }
 Then this.content is always null if i try to read it from POST
 
    }

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual model object named `object` when you submit, spring constructs it based on the parameter type and will bind the properties accordingly.

You have 2 choices to make it work

1. Store the object in the session
2. Use a `@ModelAttribute` annotated method

If neither of these are there spring will simply look at the method argument and use reflection to construct an instance of that class. So in your case it will only be `Object` and after that binding will fail.

**Store object in the session**

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("object")
public class MyController { ... }
```

Make sure that when you are finished that you call the `setComplete()` method on a `SessionStatus` object.

**Use a `@ModelAttribute` annotated method**

Instead of creating and adding the object in a request handling method create a speficic method for it.

```
@ModelAttribute("object")
public Object formBackingObject() {
    Class<?> clazz = ????; // a Random POJO is chosen, i want to use POJOs!!

    Object object = clazz.newInstance();
    return object;
}
```

This method will be called before each request handling method, so that a newly fresh object is constructed which will be used for binding.