# Spring Mvc ModelAttribute with containing class reference not working?

Tags: spring, model, controller

I want to to create different @Entity entities within the same Controller.

```
public class ContentContainer {

public Object content;

public ContentContainer(){}

public ContentContainer(Object object){
    setContent(object);
}

public Object getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(Object content) {
    this.content = content;
}

}
```

Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value="create", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String  GET(Model model) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

Class<?> clazz = ????; // a Random POJO is chosen, i want to use POJOs!!
Object object = clazz.newInstance();

model.addAttribute("mymodel", new ContentContainer(object));

return "create";        
}

@RequestMapping(value="create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Object POST(@ModelAttribute(value="mymodel") ContentContainer cc) {
    Object object = cc.getContent();
    // object == NULL but why??
    return object;
}
```

Thymeleaf page as was asked in another comment. 
That#s why i posted this
some more
text
so i can post
this additional information
dont't know 
why this is necessary.
Please excuse me.
But this has to be done
to obey the rules.

```
<head>
<title th:text="${title}">Entity create</title>
</head>
<body>


 <form action="#" th:object="${mymodel}" th:action="@{${url}}"  method="post">
<fieldset>

<table class="table table-striped">

    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 150px;">Fieldname</th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">Input</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="v : ${values}">

        <td><label th:for="${v}" th:text="${v}">Fieldname: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{__${v}__}" /></td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

     <div class="submit">
         <button type="submit" name="create" th:text="#{entity.create}">Create</button>
     </div>

 </fieldset>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

In the Post Method i get `NULL` for getContent

What am i missing?

Comment: The same as in your other question, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031858/spring-mvc-modelattribute-with-referencing-name-is-not-working

Comment: But how can i achieve it, that i can open the same page multiple times without the session getting swapped or shared between the different site request? (if i open multiple tabs to the same url, but i will pass different parameters to the url)

Comment: Please read the answer I gave 2 solutions!.

Comment: @ModelAttribute does not work too, and i don't like dealing with Session if i use it only to send changes of a pojo to a controller

Comment: Why wouldn't that work, that method is execute before every method and if a named attribute is available it should be used.

Comment: If i use ModelAttribute i don't get the values i entered for it on the website. On the POST controller method i tried using it by calling the method and i also tried injecting it as an argument on the method. Both only return me a new object from the ModelAttribute annotated method that create a blank new object.

Comment: You don't call the method spring does that for you! It works if it doesn't work for you you have something wrong in your setup!.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested your thing.

In my JSP:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="./index.do" modelAttribute="testObject">
    <h1>test for object </h1>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><form:input path="object"/></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="test Object"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

And my `testObject` is similar to your `ContentContainer`

When I debug, I found no matter what I've given in my `GET` method for getting this page, the `object` contained in the `container` return by `POST` method has always the type `String`.

And can you post your **JSP** please, because in my test there is no `convert` or `null` error, maybe there's something wrong with your JSP about the modelAttribute.

Comment: String will always work, like all primitive types, but class types do not work

Comment: What's the JSP page like? I don't get a null, but I don't think spring can convert the object.

Comment: see edit, it's a thymeleaf page, converters from spring are added automatically with the spring-thymeleaf jar published by spring

Comment: @user2000811 hey dude, something new?

Comment: `*{__${v}__}`, this bind the value to which property?

Comment: values contains all fieldnames from the java object, so v contains a single fieldname, i think spring is not intelligent enough, i would expect, that it is possible to bind an object to a name with the ModelAttribute annotation, now you have to send this name within the form and use custom coding to get all the values from the httpRequest or use MultiValueMap<String,String>  to get the values injected

Comment: Agreed, spring only knows the primitive types(List too)... for your pojos, you have to convert by yourself maybe.

Comment: My solution is to add an additional field that holds the type com.test.model.ModelA so that i can build it on my own.. if you have some suggestion where i have to hook so that i can extend @ModelAttribute to do it by name, i would appreciate it posting the complete code afterwards